# How to auto make a shortcut in the start menu upon doing a exe

Tags: python, exe, iexpress

So I am creating an installer with i-express 2.0 on Windows and I have the files and everything, but I do not see the "create shortcut automatically upon installing in the desktop / start menu" button or anything like that button. I have a giant file and there is one .exe file, I want that to be made a shortcut automatically.
(Or you can suggest another program that can).

I am running on Windows 10

My .EXE runs on python / Is coded with python

Comment: You picked a tool that apparently doesn't have this option - there are plenty of (free or paid) alternatives for creating installers that do offer this option. iExpress appears to be more of a "self-extracting archive creator" than an "installer creator". StackOverflow isn't the right place to ask for recommendations, but this WikiPedia page lists most of your options: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software

Comment: I installed one of them.